# Python file copy script - preserving a file's Creation time without leveraging third-party modules?

Tags: python

I am writing a Python script that mimics Microsoft's Robocopy (while adding predictive script completion times to the user).  I'm deploying this script in an intranet environment where its difficult to have third-party software approved so I'd like to stick to the Python 3 standard library if possible.

Does anyone know if the latest version has native modules that can alter a file's timestamp after it's been copied?  I'm trying to preserve the original file's creation date/time after it's been copied.  I know I can read it with os.path.getctime(), but I'm only aware of the third-party pywin32 module that can manipulate a file's timestamps.  Thanks in advance.